# Lazy decoding of a list with Data.Binary

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I am lazily encoding lists using this code (taken from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205597/1241368)):

```
import Data.Binary

newtype Stream a = Stream { unstream :: [a] }

instance Binary a => Binary (Stream a) where

    put (Stream [])     = putWord8 0
    put (Stream (x:xs)) = putWord8 1 >> put x >> put (Stream xs)
```

The problem is that the decoding implementation is not lazy:

```
    get = do
        t <- getWord8
        case t of
            0 -> return (Stream [])
            1 -> do x         <- get
                    Stream xs <- get
                    return (Stream (x:xs))
```

This looks to me like it should be lazy, but if we run this test code:

```
head $ unstream (decode $ encode $ Stream [1..10000000::Integer] :: Stream Integer)
```

memory usage explodes.  For some reason it wants to decode the whole list before letting me look at the first element.

Why is this not lazy, and how I can make it lazy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not lazy because the `Get` monad is a strict state monad (in [binary-0.5.0.2 to 0.5.1.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.5.1.1); it was a lazy state monad before, and in [binary-0.6.*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.6.1.0) it has become a continuation monad, I haven't analysed the strictness implications of that change):

```
-- | The parse state
data S = S {-# UNPACK #-} !B.ByteString  -- current chunk
           L.ByteString                  -- the rest of the input
           {-# UNPACK #-} !Int64         -- bytes read

-- | The Get monad is just a State monad carrying around the input ByteString
-- We treat it as a strict state monad. 
newtype Get a = Get { unGet :: S -> (# a, S #) }

-- Definition directly from Control.Monad.State.Strict
instance Monad Get where
    return a  = Get $ \s -> (# a, s #)
    {-# INLINE return #-}

    m >>= k   = Get $ \s -> case unGet m s of
                             (# a, s' #) -> unGet (k a) s'
    {-# INLINE (>>=) #-}
```

thus the final recursive

```
get >>= \x ->
get >>= \(Stream xs) ->
return (Stream (x:xs))
```

forces the entire `Stream` to be read before it can be returned.

I don't think it's possible to lazily decode a `Stream` in the `Get` monad (so a fortiori not with the `Binary` instance). But you can write a lazy decoding function using `runGetState`:

```
-- | Run the Get monad applies a 'get'-based parser on the input
-- ByteString. Additional to the result of get it returns the number of
-- consumed bytes and the rest of the input.
runGetState :: Get a -> L.ByteString -> Int64 -> (a, L.ByteString, Int64)
runGetState m str off =
    case unGet m (mkState str off) of
      (# a, ~(S s ss newOff) #) -> (a, s `join` ss, newOff)
```

First write a `Get` parser that returns a `Maybe a`,

```
getMaybe :: Binary a => Get (Maybe a)
getMaybe = do
    t <- getWord8
    case t of
      0 -> return Nothing
      _ -> fmap Just get
```

then use that to make a function of type `(ByteString,Int64) -> Maybe (a,(ByteString,Int64))`:

```
step :: Binary a => (ByteString,Int64) -> Maybe (a,(ByteString,Int64))
step (xs,offset) = case runGetState getMaybe xs offset of
                     (Just v, ys, newOffset) -> Just (v,(ys,newOffset))
                     _                       -> Nothing
```

and then you can use `Data.List.unfoldr` to lazily decode a list,

```
lazyDecodeList :: Binary a => ByteString -> [a]
lazyDecodeList xs = unfoldr step (xs,0)
```

and wrap that in a `Stream`

```
lazyDecodeStream :: Binary a => ByteString -> Stream a
lazyDecodeStream = Stream . lazyDecodeList
```

Comment: Is there a design resign why the Put monad is lazy, but the Get monad is strict?  This seems very awkward.

Comment: `Get` was lazy in `binary < 0.5`. I'm not sure about the details, but iirc, the reason to switch to a strict implementation (even using unboxed tuples) was performance. With a lazy state monad, it is terribly easy to build up huge thunks, and people ran into that problem - enormous memory consumption and slow performance - not too seldomly. Most of the time, a strict state monad is better or at least not worse than a lazy one, so overall the gain seems larger than the loss. It is probably less work to write a lazy decoder with the current implementation than to avoid leaks with the old.

Comment: I thought the whole point of having the cereal package and binary was that if you wanted strictness you use cereal.  Is there another difference?  (And thanks for all the help!)

Comment: It was changed for performance reasons. When binary was added to GHC, we found that it was 2 to 3x faster when using a strict state monad.

Comment: Are there any plans to get a lazy version like this into `binary`, e.g. `Data.Binary.Lazy`? With `unGet` and the likes not being exported, obviously we cannot use this as a workaround.

Comment: @nh2 I don't think so. You can't mix lazy and strict decoding, so it would have to be a separate implementation. Maybe a `Data.Binary[.Put/Get].Lazy` would be included if a feature request gets enough support. Otherwise, one could make one's own package providing lazy de- and serialization.